# Как выгрузить данные из xlsx файла в виде списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

У меня есть таблица xlsx https://fex.net/ru/s/dxlmzvc
Как мне представить эти данные в виде списка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

один из вариантов - использовать библиотеку pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_excel(r'result_final.xlsx')
>>> df
     Unnamed: 0         card_name
0             1           Minions
1             2           Archers
2             3            Knight
3             4     Spear_Goblins
4             5           Goblins
..          ...               ...
100         101    Electro_Spirit

[101 rows x 2 columns]
>>> lst = df['card_name'].values
>>> lst
array(['Minions', 'Archers', 'Knight', 'Spear_Goblins', 'Goblins',
       ...  'Electro_Spirit'], dtype=object)
```